# samsung galaxy prevail download mode drivers

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, windows, usb-drivers

I have windows 8.1 and a galaxy prevail running 2.3.6.
I can put the device into download mode, but windows says device not properly attached or something. I'm guessing I don't have the download mode drivers, but i do have the Samsung drivers installed, and it connects normally. Am I missing download mode drivers? if so, where do I get them?

Comment: I had to enable adb on my s2 for download mode to work correct.

Comment: I have usb debugging enabled

Comment: Did you goto download mode through adb on PC or through hardware buttons?

Comment: And are you going through wired or wireless adb?

Comment: Hardware buttons (pwr,vol-,camera) and wired